Invalid access when reading a packet using bpf_loop
I'm trying to parse the first couple of bytes of a packet passed to a stream_parser program. However, I'm running into a few problems that make little sense to me. Here's the program:
    __u32 len = 256;
    // uncommenting this breaks it even using the regular for loop
    // if (len > skb->len) len = skb->len;

    if (bpf_skb_pull_data(skb, len) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    char *data_end = (char *)(long)skb->data_end;
    char *data = (char *)(long)skb->data;

    if (data + len > data_end) {
        return -1;
    }

    __u32 k = 0;
    bpf_for(k, 0, len) {     
        __u32 i = k & 0xFF;
        if (i < len && data + i > data_end) break;
        bpf_printk("data[i] = %d", data[i]);
    }

    // this works!
    // for (__u32 i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    //     if (data + i > data_end) break;
    //     bpf_printk("data[i] = %d", data[i]);
    // }

And here's output of the verifier:
0: R1=ctx() R10=fp0
; int bpf_prog_parser(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
0: (bf) r6 = r1                       ; R1=ctx() R6_w=ctx()
; if (bpf_skb_pull_data(skb, len) < 0) {
1: (b7) r2 = 256                      ; R2_w=256
2: (85) call bpf_skb_pull_data#39     ; R0_w=scalar()
3: (b7) r1 = 0                        ; R1_w=0
; if (bpf_skb_pull_data(skb, len) < 0) {
4: (6d) if r1 s> r0 goto pc+50        ; R0_w=scalar(smin=0,umax=0x7fffffffffffffff,var_off=(0x0; 0x7fffffffffffffff)) R1_w=0
; char *data_end = (char *)(long)skb->data_end;
5: (61) r8 = *(u32 *)(r6 +80)         ; R6_w=ctx() R8_w=pkt_end()
; char *data = (char *)(long)skb->data;
6: (61) r9 = *(u32 *)(r6 +76)         ; R6_w=ctx() R9_w=pkt(r=0)
; if (data + len > data_end) {
7: (bf) r1 = r9                       ; R1_w=pkt(r=0) R9_w=pkt(r=0)
8: (07) r1 += 256                     ; R1=pkt(off=256,r=0)
; if (data + len > data_end) {
9: (2d) if r1 > r8 goto pc+45         ; R1=pkt(off=256,r=256) R8=pkt_end()
10: (bf) r7 = r10                     ; R7_w=fp0 R10=fp0
; 
11: (07) r7 += -24                    ; R7_w=fp-24
; bpf_for(k, 0, len) {     
12: (bf) r1 = r7                      ; R1_w=fp-24 R7_w=fp-24
13: (b7) r2 = 0                       ; R2_w=0
14: (b7) r3 = 256                     ; R3_w=256
15: (85) call bpf_iter_num_new#76394          ; R0_w=scalar() fp-24_w=iter_num(ref_id=1,state=active,depth=0) refs=1
; bpf_for(k, 0, len) {     
16: (bf) r1 = r7                      ; R1=fp-24 R7=fp-24 refs=1
17: (85) call bpf_iter_num_next#76396 18: R0_w=rdonly_mem(id=2,ref_obj_id=1,sz=4) R6=ctx() R7=fp-24 R8=pkt_end() R9=pkt(r=256) R10=fp0 fp-24=iter_num(ref_id=1,state=active,depth=1) refs=1
; bpf_for(k, 0, len) {     
18: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+17      ; R0_w=rdonly_mem(id=2,ref_obj_id=1,sz=4) refs=1
19: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r0 +0)         ; R0_w=rdonly_mem(id=2,ref_obj_id=1,sz=4) R1_w=scalar(smin=0,smax=umax=0xffffffff,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) refs=1
; bpf_for(k, 0, len) {     
20: (25) if r1 > 0xff goto pc+15      ; R1_w=scalar(smin=smin32=0,smax=umax=smax32=umax32=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) refs=1
; if (i < len && data + i > data_end) break;
21: (bf) r2 = r9                      ; R2_w=pkt(r=256) R9=pkt(r=256) refs=1
22: (0f) r2 += r1                     ; R1=scalar(smin=smin32=0,smax=umax=smax32=umax32=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) R2=pkt(id=5,r=0,smin=smin32=0,smax=umax=smax32=umax32=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) refs=1
; if (i < len && data + i > data_end) break;
23: (2d) if r2 > r8 goto pc+12        ; R2=pkt(id=5,r=0,smin=smin32=0,smax=umax=smax32=umax32=255,var_off=(0x0; 0xff)) R8=pkt_end() refs=1
; bpf_printk("data[i] = %d", data[i]);
24: (71) r3 = *(u8 *)(r2 +0)
invalid access to packet, off=0 size=1, R2(id=5,off=0,r=0)
R2 offset is outside of the packet
processed 55 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 5 peak_states 5 mark_read 2

I have three questions:

Why does this particular code example not work?
Why does the for loop at the bottom work, but bpf_loop not? I would use the regular for loop but this also doesn't work because the number of instructions explodes.
Finally, at the very top I want to constrain len to skb->len. Doing so breaks the verification for both loop variants. Why is that? After all, the upper limit of 256 still holds.

Essentially, I just want to read the first couple of bytes. I know that the verifier is  not perfect but I assume that very basic parsing is possible.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Hello, can you also mention the version of kernel you are using. I know there is a bug in bpf_loop that may cause the issue you are observing. https://www.spinics.net/lists/bpf/msg104984.html . In my experience, bpf sk_skb_parser and sk_skb_verdict are also not very stable. Moreover, to make everything worse, the clang sometimes applies optimizations that cause the verifier to complain about the safety of the code.

Thansk @FarbodShahinfar, I'm indeed using kernel v6.5 so this might be it! Yes also noticed that some checks that would be helpful to the verifier are optimized out. Are you aware of a way to force the compiler to add the checks even if deemed unnecessary?

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any technique to fix the challenge with the compiler. Disabling the optimization will not work, in my experience. It would cause some other issues such as the program being too complex for the verifier, not doing the function inline-ing and other issues. I notice that performing a mask on variables used as offset or length sometimes help (e.g., off = off & 0x0fff). Make sure the mask is large enough for your purpose.
